# Using escaping string with quotes in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, quoting

I have a very simple question. Assume, I want to do select:

```
select '''Y''' asd, q'['Y']' asd from dual
```

Okay, it works. Then I switch it to

```
select '''N''' asd, q'['N']' asd from dual
```

And it fails with ORA-01756! So have I missed something in manuals about quoting with Q-letter? By the way I'm using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you try this? Does a simple, clean SQLPlus session give this error? These both work well for me

Comment: What you've posted seems fine. Which client are you using? (Only immediate thought is that something is somehow confused by the `n'...'` syntax for an nchar literal... seems more likely that you're running something slightly different to what you've shown though?)

Comment: I did this in PL/SQL Developer using SQL-Window and it gave an error. I tried it in Command Window and it worked fine. So I guess Alex Poole is right and PL/SQL Developer looks at my string like it's nchar literal.

Comment: No problem in PL/SQL Developer SQL window here.

Comment: Maybe it is connected with NLS settings?

Comment: No, I can't see it being anything to do with NLS settings. Are you using an old version, maybe?

Comment: Yes, you were right! I was using v.9 and updated it to v.10 and it works like magic! Great thanks for help, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I was using v.9 of PL/SQL Developer. After moving to the v.10 the issue was gone.